# import typings of package with different name

Tags: angularjs, typescript, webpack, typescript2.0, ng-idle

I am converting exiting project to typescript. The project is using a package    [ng-idle](https://github.com/HackedByChinese/ng-idle) and it has @types package with name [angular-idle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/angular-idle) and the file `@types/angular-idle/index.d.ts` contains

```
declare module 'angular' {
    export namespace idle {
         ....
```

How do I import this package

```
   import * as ngIdle from 'angular-idle'
```

or

```
   import * as ngIdle from 'ng-idle'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this

```
import {idle} from 'angular'
const blah = idle.BLAH
```

You can even rename the namespace on import

```
import {idle as ng_idle} from 'angular'
const blah = ng_idle.BLAH
```

If you already import angular

```
 import * as angular from 'angular'
 import idle = angular.idle
 const blah = idle.BLAH
```

(or use `angular.idle` directly)

Comment: but the package name is `ng-idle` and `angular-idle` and not `angular`, so the package name has nothing to do with the name specified in quotes while doing import??

Comment: if I use `angular-idle` directly, webpack gives error

Comment: It does not matter. What matters to the compiler is 1) that there is module named "angular" in node_modules, 2) that the name `idle` is exported in the definition files of external module "angular". Use the imports above and check [this example](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/angular-idle/angular-idle-tests.ts) for usage

Comment: while what you said works in case of ngIdle, same thing is not working in case of ngStorage, I have very similar issue like this with angular.storage and there it does not work.. [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46276113/import-ngstorage-with-webpack)