# import ngstorage with webpack

Tags: angularjs, typescript, import, ng-storage

I am trying to import npm package [ngstorage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngstorage) in my angularjs v1.x (typescript) project using [@types/ngstorage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/ngstorage)

the `index.d.ts` contains

```
declare namespace angular.storage {

        export interface IStorageService {
        }
}
```

if I do like below in my `.ts` files

```
import * as angular from 'angular';

var storage: angular.storage.IStorageService;
```

I am getting compilation error

> namespace angular and no exported member storage

Comment: can you edit with your webpack.config.js file

Comment: @PanosK sorry I really didnt get what you wanted to ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I was able to get it work

```
        import { ngStorage } from 'ngStorage';
```

the namespace and not the package name should matter when doing an import